# PETCs - How should one initialize PetscRandom?

Tags: petsc, c, random-number-generation

The documentation of PETSc shows an example of usage:

```
  PetscRandomCreate(PETSC_COMM_SELF,&r);
  PetscRandomSetType(r,PETSCRAND48);
  PetscRandomGetValue(r,&value1);
  PetscRandomGetValueReal(r,&value2);
  PetscRandomDestroy(&r);
```

In the example random 1, we can find also the use of PetscRandomSeed.

However, it seems not to be enough for attaching a PetscRandom variable to an object.

The following code works well for any number of procs:

```
#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "TSInjectCreate"
PetscErrorCode  TSInjectCreate(MPI_Comm comm,TSInject *ininject){
  PetscErrorCode ierr;
  size_t         t;
  PetscInt       i;
  PetscReal       r;
  TSInject       inject;

  PetscFunctionBegin;
  PetscValidPointer(ininject,1);
  *ininject = NULL;
  ierr                       = PetscClassIdRegister("TSInject",&TSINJECT_CLASSID);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscHeaderCreate(inject,TSINJECT_CLASSID,"TSInject","Injection of SDC","TS",comm,TSInjectDestroy, TSInjectView);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscRandomCreate( comm,&inject->ran);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscRandomSetType(inject->ran, PETSCRAND48);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscRandomSeed(inject->ran);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscRandomGetValue(inject->ran, &r);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  *ininject = inject;

  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}
```

But as soon as I use `PetscRandomGetValue(inject->ran, &r);` in another function, it works only when mpi is launched with one proc.

Why?

EDIT:

The error comes exactly (and weirdly) from the comparison:

```
PetscErrorCode  TSInjection(TSInject inject, Vec X)
{
  PetscReal       r,err;
  Vec             Y;
  PetscErrorCode ierr;

  PetscFunctionBegin;
  ierr = PetscRandomGetValue(inject->ran, &r);CHKERRQ(ierr);
ierr = VecView(X, 0);CHKERRQ(ierr);    // works
  if(r  > inject->proba){ PetscFunctionReturn(0);}
        ierr = VecView(X, 0);CHKERRQ(ierr);      // stucks the execution
 ...          
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}
```

If I replace `r` by 0.1 for example, everything works fine. What is all the more surprising is that displaying r doesn't stuck the execution.

Comment: Is there a reason your inject object should survive passing out of scope?

Comment: Yes the reason is that it receives parameters and these parameters will choose which function should be called. In this initialization function, non important lines were deleted.

Comment: Moreover, the problem occurs on several machines. Linux/mac, same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, a work-around is too employ a DIY random function. In my context, I have given up with PetscRandom to write:

```
PetscErrorCode TSInjectRandInt(TSInject inject, PetscInt *r)  // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
{
    PetscFunctionBegin;
    inject->next = inject->next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    *r = PetscAbs((PetscInt)(inject->next/65536) % 32768);
    PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}


PetscErrorCode TSInjectRandReal(TSInject inject, PetscReal *r)  {
  PetscInt i;

  PetscFunctionBegin;
  TSInjectRandInt(inject, &i);
  *r = ((PetscReal)i)/32767.0;
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}

PetscErrorCode TSInjectRandSeed(TSInject inject, PetscInt seed)
{
    PetscFunctionBegin;
    inject->next = seed;
    PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}
```

However, one should notice that RAND_MAX is fixed and that the generator is clearly very easy. It has the only advantage of working.